# Undocumented transaction types

Tags: coinbase-api

While integrating with the [Transactions API](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#transaction-resource) I noticed the following undocumented types:

- `pro_deposit`: seems to be equivalent to `exchange_deposit`
- `pro_withdrawal`: seems to be equivalent to `exchange_withdrawal`
- `order`: similar to a `send` but tracks a payment to a merchant
- `delayed_canceled`: not sure what it represents

Can anyone point me to an updated list of transaction types and/or explain what `delayed_canceled` transactions represent?